# Issue with task system - tasks will run exactly twice (re-post once)

Tags: c, linked-list, avr

I've attempted to write a simple task system for my AVR.  The code for this is [here](http://pastebin.com/vGtGvi5e).  (Sadly, this is also the MWE.)

The basic idea behind the system is that a periodic timer interrupt sets a flag, which the main application loop then checks in order to run a task.  The task processing function is re-entrant, so will be executed exactly once per iteration for each pending task:

```
while (1) {
    if (flTask) {
        flTask = task_process_next();
    }

    // Do other awesome stuff in the loop
}
```

In order to keep the design simple, a task which wants to run periodically is required to re-post itself.

So a simple heartbeat task might be added like this:

```
task_add(heartbeat_task, 0);
```

And its code might look like this:

```
void heartbeat_task(void)
{
    task_add(heartbeat_task, 10000); // Re-post task

    led_toggle(LEDGreen);
    xbee_send_heartbeat(BASE_STATION_ID);
}
```

---

My problem is this: each periodic task will run exactly twice.

I have confirmed through toggling pins (as you can see in the code I linked to) that during each task's first and repeat execution the `task_add` method is called.

However, despite apparently adding the task the second time, it never runs.

I have further tried simplifying the code in `task_process_next` considerably (including by adding a loop to process all tasks in one call, and by changing the run condition to ignore overflow).  Neither of these modifications proved successful.

---

My question is this: *have I messed up some detail of my linked-list implementation which could cause re-posted tasks to be ignored?*

In particular, have I accidentally made it so that nodes in the list can be skipped over without being evaluated or run?

I understand that it is difficult to debug this sort of problem without running on the hardware, but I'm hoping that another set of eyes will see what I've missed.

I'm happy to provide any additional information / do any tests which are necessary.

Comment: I think it's something in your overflow logic. The first time it runs almost immediately (since you added it with delay `0`) then the second run probably goes in without an overflow (if `delay` isn't extremely large). The ones that cause an overflow may not be running, so check that. What actually happens if `ticks >= runTime`and `overflow` is true?

Comment: @mbratch - in that case it shouldn't run until `ticks` itself overflows (the else if clause).  I tried excluding the overflow logic by making the run condition `ticks >= task->runTime`, but that didn't fix it either.  Is there something else like that I should try?

Comment: How much time is a `tick`?

Comment: It's about 100us at the moment, so pretty long.  (The heartbeat task re-posts every second)

Comment: That's about 6.5s (maximum) before you'll see an overflow.

Comment: Based on the overflow logic, it does look like it should eventually run the task, although perhaps not on the desired interval. I'm actually wondering now if doing the `task_add` (which also calls `task_queue`) is causing an issue since that happens in the midst of `task_process_next` updating the queue.

Comment: @mbratch - I was wondering that as well, but the logic checks out to me (even if it changes `task->next`, that change should be passed on as `task` is, after all, a pointer).  That's why I was hoping for another set of eyes, in case I've done something silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queue was being corrupted when a task at its end was removed:

```
    if (prev) {
        prev->next = task->next;
    } else {
        tasks.head = task->next;
    }

    // Adding these lines fixed the problem
    if (task == tasks.tail) {
        tasks.tail = prev;
    }
```